# Python Selenium how to interact with two different website formats in one code

Tags: python, selenium

there are two formats on the website I am interacting:

- `http://15256160037.58food.com/contact/`
- `http://hubeianran.58food.com/contact/`

Also two links format: (with title in a[1] or a[2]

```
<div class="company-left-title">
            <a href="http://hubeianran.58food.com/" target="_blank">湖北安然保健品有限公司</a>
                <p><a href="/company_hubeianran.html" target="_blank">［企业黄页]</a></p>
                
            </div>
```

OR

```
<div class="company-left-title">
<a href="javascript:Go('/qy-l-0-4-3595-3595-1.html');">
            </a><a href="http://15256160037.58food.com/" target="_blank">亳州市九熹堂药业有限公司</a>  
            </div>
```

I am trying to get contact info, website on those websites and put them into a csv. in the second format, I have to click in another button to get the whole info

I used:

```
driver.get('http://www.58food.com/qy-l-0-3595.html')
while True:
  try:
     links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="company-left-title"]/a[2]')]
  except:
     links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="company-left-title"]/a[1]')]
  locs = [loc.text for loc in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="company-text"]/p')]
    for link,loc in zip(links,locs):
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.get(link)
        windows = driver.window_handles
        driver.switch_to.window(windows[-1])
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('联系方式').click()
        try:
          company = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="rclefttop"]/strong').text
          con_num = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="rcleftlist"]/i[1]').text
          driver.back()
          driver.back()
        except:
          company = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="px14 lh18"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').text
          driver.find_element_by_id('glo_contactway_content').click()
          con_num = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="archives dr-archives relative"]/p[1]').text
          driver.find_element_by_id('close').click()
          website = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="px14 lh18"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a').text
          driver.back()
          driver.back()
        dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'col1':company,'col2':con_num,'col3':con_num2,'col4':loc,'col5':website},index=[0])

    try:
        next_page = driver.find_element_by_link_text("下一页")
        next_page.click()
    except:
          print('No more pages')
          break
```

But

> ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
> (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)

Could someone please help with that issue?

Comment: Should the try/except blocks be part of the for loop?

Comment: I am not sure about this.. I edited with it in the loop now

Comment: What do you mean you are not sure? Did you write the code?

Comment: yes but same error, for the 'except' part, it just do nothing,

Answer (score 0):

May be the object you are trying to click was still loading and that is why not clickable. Try Explicit wait till the object you are trying to click is visible and clickable.
Refer to [this](https://www.techbeamers.com/selenium-webdriver-waits-python/) link for more information.

Comment: hi, the website just cannot click on driver.find_element_by_id('glo_contactway_content').click() even wait

Comment: Brother check if you are using the right ID, or try using XPATH of that element coz i have searched by the id but no element was found with the ID 'glo_contactway_content'